# Install sqlplus in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sql, ubuntu-16.04

I've tried installing sqlplus in ubuntu 16.04 using this link http://webikon.com/cases/installing-oracle-sql-plus-client-on-ubuntu but upon final step it required user-name and password. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a database *client*. 
Do you have a database? 
Do you have a database server? 
If so, use a username and password from that. 
If not, a database client isn’t going to do you much good.

Comment: I don't have a database, how do I solve the problem now? Or can i even solve it at all?

Comment: What do you expect to be able to do with only a database client?  If you want to do database stuff, you have to have a database.